# Сочетается ли слово "бережливость" с предлогом "к"?

Tags: предлоги

Правильно ли словосочетание "Бережливость к используемым ресурсам"? Или лучше заменить, например, на "бережливость по отношению к используемым ресурсам"?

Comment: "Бережливое отношение к государственному имуществу." - словарь Ушакова "бережливый". По-к - это кручено-перекручено.